# Does cider need to be kept out of light?

Tags: cider, light

In brewing a cider, do I need to be as concerned with exposure to light as I do with beer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hops react with light to create skunky flavors. So long as you didn't use hops in your cider (not unheard of), you don't need to be overly concerned about light. I still wouldn't recommend fermenting or storing it in direct sunlight if at all possible.